# Django cms : how to get real page id

Tags: django-cms

I was using django cms 2.3.3 and everything was fine, and today I try to upgrade to 2.4.2

everything seems to be fine, just I can't understand why a page can have several page id, ie in admin, when I edit a page, i go for instance on /cms/page/2
but if I print it's id in menu with {{ child.id }} ,  the id is different, for instance 114.
Is it because I had to use shell command "cms moderator on"?

one more question, when I do any modification, I always have to validate "last changes" by clicking on green tick from admin list of pages. Is there a way to avoid that ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Starting with CMS 2.4, all changes made to a page or plugin need to be approved. This "moderation" system was introduced to allow users the possibility of having a draft version or a page and a live version. So this means that for every page django-cms has two records of the page, one "live" and one "draft". This is why you encounter different ids. You could easily verify this by running in a django shell:

```
from cms.models import Page

print Page.objects.filter(title_set__title='yourpagetitle')
```

the above should print two pages.

Regarding `cms moderator on`, this command 
 publishes all pages and makes sure that all changes from draft are applied to live.

To answer your question, no there's no way to avoid having to approve the changes.